# highcharts line graph with ajax

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I would like to implement a simple line graph with ajax in which only two points
x will be the hours and y will be the count of calls.

CODE :

```
<script>
    function getData() {
          $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: "http://localhost/demo_chart/test.php",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response_data) {        
                new_data = $.map(response_data, function(i){
                        return {x: i['date'],y: i['count']};
                });
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line'  
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Count vs. Time'
                    },    
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Time'
                        },
                        type: 'Time',
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Count'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                                name: 'Test',
                                data: new_data
                            }]
                });
            }
        })
    }
$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
})  

</script>
```

Output of http://localhost/demo_chart/test.php is same as below :

```
{"date":["13:00:00","13:00:01","13:00:02","13:00:03","13:00:04"],"count":["1","2","3","4","2"]}
```

But still graph is not generating. So i would like to know what is the problem here.

Anyone like to share some hint which can resolve this problem ?

Expected output is :

```
X- axis : show all date 
Y-axis : show count
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your mapping function, for example:

```
var response = {
    "date": ["13:00:00", "13:00:01", "13:00:02", "13:00:03", "13:00:04"],
    "count": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "2"]
};

new_data = $.map(response.date, function(el, index) {
    return {
        name: el,
        y: parseInt(response['count'][index])
    };
});
```

Additionally, with that data structure, I recommend you to use `category` axis type.

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    type: 'category'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ptx6fy2q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: Thanks for reply but here x axis showing time is 0,1,2,3,4 but it should be 13:00:00,13:00:01,13:00:02:13:00:03,13:00:04

Comment: Hi @Ankit Doshi, Sorry, you are right. I have edited my answer - please check the result now.

Comment: @ppotazek, Thanks for the reply. But would you like to share what you have edited? Sorry to bother but don't get the correct idea. So will you please share if you get some time.

Comment: @Ankit Doshi, I have corrected `xAxis.type` from `categories` to `category`.